# Calendar DayPilot "Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined" when using a different Database

Tags: javascript, php, json, calendar, daypilot

I am still a debutant in JavaScript/Json (I've never worked with Json) and I have a problem when trying to use DayPilot Calendar. (I am also French, so forgive my mistakes please).

http://code.daypilot.org/17910/html5-event-calendar-open-source

When I download sources and use it it works perfectly, but when I try to adapt it to my database, I can't make it work.

Source Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Event Calendar</title>
        <!-- demo stylesheet -->
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="media/layout.css" />    

            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/calendar_g.css" />    
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/calendar_green.css" />    
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/calendar_traditional.css" />    
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/calendar_transparent.css" />    
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/calendar_white.css" />    

        <!-- helper libraries -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- daypilot libraries -->
            <script src="js/daypilot/daypilot-all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="header">
                <div class="bg-help">
                    <div class="inBox">
                        <h1 id="logo"><a href='http://code.daypilot.org/17910/html5-event-calendar-open-source'>HTML5 Event Calendar</a></h1>
                        <p id="claim"><a href="http://javascript.daypilot.org/">DayPilot for JavaScript</a> - AJAX Calendar/Scheduling Widgets for JavaScript/HTML5/jQuery</p>
                        <hr class="hidden" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="hideSkipLink">
            </div>
            <div class="main">

                <div style="float:left; width: 160px;">
                    <div id="nav"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 160px;">
                    <div id="dp"></div>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var nav = new DayPilot.Navigator("nav");
                    nav.showMonths = 3;
                    nav.skipMonths = 3;
                    nav.selectMode = "week";
                    nav.onTimeRangeSelected = function(args) {
                        dp.startDate = args.day;
                        dp.update();
                        loadEvents();
                    };
                    nav.init();

                    var dp = new DayPilot.Calendar("dp");
                    dp.viewType = "Week";

                    dp.onEventMoved = function (args) {
                        $.post("backend_move.php", 
                                {
                                    id: args.e.id(),
                                    newStart: args.newStart.toString(),
                                    newEnd: args.newEnd.toString()
                                }, 
                                function() {
                                    console.log("Moved.");
                                });
                    };

                    dp.onEventResized = function (args) {
                        $.post("backend_resize.php", 
                                {
                                    id: args.e.id(),
                                    newStart: args.newStart.toString(),
                                    newEnd: args.newEnd.toString()
                                }, 
                                function() {
                                    console.log("Resized.");
                                });
                    };

                    // event creating
                    dp.onTimeRangeSelected = function (args) {
                        var name = prompt("New event name:", "Event");
                        dp.clearSelection();
                        if (!name) return;
                        var e = new DayPilot.Event({
                            start: args.start,
                            end: args.end,
                            id: DayPilot.guid(),
                            resource: args.resource,
                            text: name
                        });
                        dp.events.add(e);

                        $.post("backend_create.php", 
                                {
                                    start: args.start.toString(),
                                    end: args.end.toString(),
                                    name: name
                                }, 
                                function() {
                                    console.log("Created.");
                                });

                    };

                    dp.onEventClick = function(args) {
                        alert("clicked: " + args.e.id());
                    };

                    dp.init();

                    loadEvents();

                    function loadEvents() {
                        var start = dp.visibleStart();
                        var end = dp.visibleEnd();

                        $.post("backend_events.php", 
                        {
                            start: start.toString(),
                            end: end.toString()
                        }, 
                        function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            dp.events.list = data;
                            dp.update();
                        });
                    }

                </script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#theme").change(function(e) {
                        dp.theme = this.value;
                        dp.update();
                    });
                });  
                </script>

            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And backend_events.php :

```
 <?php
    require_once '_db.php'; 

    $start = '2015-02-22 00:00:00';
    $end = '2015-09-22 00:00:00';

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE NOT ((end <= :start) OR (start >= :end))');

    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    class Event {}
    $events = array();

    foreach($result as $row) {
      $e = new Event();
      $e->id = '1';
      $e->text = 'coucou';
      $e->start = '2015-05-13T10:00:00';
      $e->end = '2015-05-13T12:00:00';
      $events[] = $e;
    }


    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($events);

    ?>
```

It put all events at the same date (It did it like this for tests), but it works !

And when I try to modify backend_events.php, using my database, Events don't appear on the calendar, and I get the error "Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined" in the console.

I'm not even using what I get from my database as you can see !

```
<?php

    // Insertion de tous les prérequis
    include '../Config/prerequis.php';
    $bdd = Donnee::getInstance()->connexion;

$start = '2015-02-22 00:00:00';
$end = '2015-09-22 00:00:00';

$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM CRENEAU WHERE NOT ((Date_fin <= :start) OR (Date_debut >= :end)) AND ID_CONTRAT=16');

$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();


class Event {}
$events = array();

// foreach($result as $row) {
  // $e = new Event();
  // $e->id = $row['ID'];
  // $e->text = 'coucou';
  // $e->start = implode('T',explode(' ', $row['Date_debut']));
  // echo implode('T',explode(' ', $row['Date_debut'])).'<br>';
  // $e->end = implode('T',explode(' ', $row['Date_fin']));
  // $events[] = $e;
// }

foreach($result as $row) {
  $e = new Event();
  $e->id = '1';
  $e->text = 'coucou';
  $e->start = '2015-05-13T10:00:00';
  $e->end = '2015-05-13T12:00:00';
  $events[] = $e;
}


header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($events);

?>
```

I've tried to fix it for days, I even ask friends who are more qualified, I can find the solution. So if you have idea I would be gratefull !

Thanks,
Marine.

Comment: You should try to check the response of the "backend_events.php" $.post() call using browser Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-I in Chrome). It looks like it doesn't return a correct JSON array.

Comment: There is nothing on the console. But when I load the page backend_events.php this is what I get from the echo json_encode($events) :   

[{"id":"1","text":"coucou","start":"2015-05-13T10:00:00","end":"2015-05-13T12:00:00"}]

And I get the same thing with the working one.

Answer (score 0):

We've found the solution.
So it was an encodind problem,

I do an include '../Config/prerequis.php';
An in the file prerequis.php I do other include, an files I was trying to include where encode in UTF-8 instead of UTF-8 without Bom.

I works perfectly now!